# ADODB SQLServer connection with Seek and Index

Tags: sql-server, adodb

In my program I want connect to SQL Server using ADODB.Connection, then read the data using ADODB.RecordSet, and use Index and Seek to find the searched record.

I tried using this connection string `Provider=SQLNCLI11;;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;`, `adOpenDynamic` as cursorType, `adLockOptimistic` as LockType and `adCmdTable` as CommandType.
But when I try to call the Supports method on recordset with adSeek or adIndex returns false.

There is a way to connect to SQL Server and open a Recordset with support for seek and index?

---

Edit here the code:

```
LOCAL oCn, nCursor, nLock,oRS
oCn                     := CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
oCn:ConnectionString    := "Provider=SQLNCLI11;;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TLPosWin;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;"
oRS                     := CreateObject( "ADODB.RecordSet" )
nCursor                 := adOpenDynamic
nLock                   := adLockOptimistic
oRS:CursorLocation      := adUseServer
oRS:Open("Articoli",oCn, nCursor, nLock, adCmdTable)
? "seek",oRS:Supports(0x200000),"index",oRS:Supports(0x100000) //both false
oRS:Index := "Articoli_ARTART" //Error
oRS:Seek('=',1,'000611') //Error
```

Comment: Why would you need such code? This would mean you've created a client or server-side cursor in a pre-.NET language like VB6 or VBScript. That was  a bad idea back in 1998. Use *disconnected* recordsets instead. Write a SQL query that reads only the data you want so you *don't* need to iterate over the data just to find the records you want.

Comment: I must use inherited code and convert it from a database engine to sql server. Looking around I see that recordSet should behave like I need. The problem is there is the methods but they are unsupported.
There should be a way to do it.

Comment: The methods *are* supported as they are part of the ADO API, but using them this way was always a bad idea. You haven't posted your code though. You didn't even mention the language you use. Someone that *hadn't* used VB6 back then wouldn't even know what you're talking about

Comment: As for `use inherited code`, that code wouldn't work if those methods weren't available. Without knowing what you tried to do, I can only point to the documentation and the [Seek Method and Index Property Example (VB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/seek-method-and-index-property-example-vb?view=sql-server-2017) page. I'll have to repeat though, you *DON'T NEED THEM* to find a row by its key value. Just write a proper query

Comment: I am using harbour, but ADODB is used in PHP also, I don't post the code because I don't think is relevant, and since harbour is not widely used, it can be misleading , I described what the code do. I saw the example, and it does not use SQL Server. I don't undestand why is a bad idea, I have a table: articles, and I know that the index IArt is (mag,codeId) I want do `oRS.seek(1,'023')` what is wrong with this?

Comment: ADODB was used by VB6. It's a COM interface. Way back when PHP didn't have good database support (no query parameters for example) people used ADODB on Windows to connect to SQL Server. That's changed now. `Index` and `Seek` were meant for *dBase* and *Clipper* file-based databases, not servers like SQL Server, Oracle, DB2,MySQL, PostgreSQL. In those servers you don't care about the index name. You just write `select a,b,c from Articles where mag='A' and codeId=3` and the server itself chooses which indexes to use

Comment: With ADODB, you should write the query you want, with the `WHERE` conditions you want, and load only the required data. There's no reason at all to use the APIs that only made sense for the file-based database of the 1990s

Comment: If ADODB was used in VB6, and now PHP has good database support, what is the way to connect to Sql Server? I googled it and I don't found it! ODBC is older than ADODB, ADODB is only by COM and it looks is not used anymore...

Comment: this couldn't be further from the truth. In fact, now that SQL Server runs on Linux, ODBC is the preferred way

Comment: Microsoft publishes its own PHP drivers now. Check [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for a step-by-step guide. That guide shows how to use the SQL Server driver directly or through the PDO API

Comment: The point is that I have a program that use the API of 1990 and I MUST convert to SQLServer.. it is almost 10K lines of code... with massive use of database